# Can XSD define a wildcard complex type?

Tags: xml, xsd

Say I don't know what an element's name will be, but I do know what it's children will be. For example, the names "foo" and "bar" are not prescribed but "A", "B" & "C" are.

```
<example>
    <foo>
        <A>A</A>
        <B>B</B>
        <C>C</C>
    </foo>
    <bar>
        <A>A</A>
        <B>B</B>
        <C>C</C>
    </bar>
</example>
```

I cannot leave the `name` attribute out because that's a violation. I would expect to be able to do this instead:

```
<xs:element name="example">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:any>
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="A" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="B" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="C" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:any>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This does not work either, `<xs:any>` can only contain annotations and refuses a type.

Is there something I can do with namespaces that will work with unknown element names? Should I give up, not attempt to validate the children and just document what the contents must be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot quite achieve what you want to do there in XML Schema. There is a close solution, but not quite what you want:

```
<xs:element name="example">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Now you could provide separate schemas for the elements that can occur in there, e.g. one for `foo`, under a separate namespace and in a separate schema file:

```
<xs:element name="foo">
    <xs:complexType>
        ....
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

That's about all you can do (it's your "multiple namespaces" solution). You can't avoid listing the elements entirely. If that's not good enough, then `<xsd:any>` with `processContents` set to `skip` is your only solution, followed by external validation (code, Schematron, etc)

Comment: External validation is my only remaining option.

Answer (score 3):

You could try doing this with [substitution groups](http://www.xfront.com/ElementHierarchy.html):

```
<xs:element name="example">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="ABCSequence" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="ABCSequence" abstract="true" type="ABCSeq" />
<xs:complexType name="ABCSeq">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="A" type="xsd:string" />
      <xs:element name="B" type="xsd:string" />
      <xs:element name="C" type="xsd:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="foo" substitutionGroup="ABCSequence" type="ABCSeq" />
<xs:element name="bar" substitutionGroup="ABCSequence" type="ABCSeq" />
```

I'm not sure if that will allow arbitrary external elements to be added in without declaring their types (via `xsi:type` attributes) but it does at least allow describing the sort of document you're after.

Comment: +1 for a neat trick. If I could get every past and future developer involved to include substitutions with their XML this answer would win, but unfortunately that's not possible.

Comment: If you're wanting every future developer to conform to your schema, you're on a losing battle. I've seen what people call XML. I've seen how they “parse” it. Dear god, I've seen what they do… Going with `xsi:type` annotations and putting _your_ parser into validating mode (it's usually off by default) is perhaps your only hope. (That and asking Obi Wan.)